# Symfony/FOSFacebook - Unable to generate a URL for the named route "fos_facebook_channel"

Tags: symfony, channel, fosfacebookbundle

After integrating the FOSfacebookBundle in my Symfony2 project, I get this error when trying to execute my project:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "fos_facebook_channel" as such route does not exist.") in MyBundle::layout.html.twig at line 32.
```

This is the line 32:

```
{{ facebook_initialize({'xfbml': true, 'fbAsyncInit': 'onFbInit();'}) }}
```

I just checked if the fos_facebook_channel does have a route in the file FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml and it does:

```
<route id="fos_facebook_channel" pattern="/channel.html">
    <default key="_controller">FOSFacebookBundle:Facebook:channel</default>
    <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
</route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

`fos_facebook_channel:
    resource: "@FOSFacebookBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"`

to your `app\config\routing.yml` file.